# How to Manipulate Hyperlinks Dynamically in Typescript React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get the title to also be the hyperlink. However, I need to add dashes for the hyperlinks to work on articles with titles that are longer than one word. What would be the best method to achieve this?

Current Code:

`https://example.com/example 01`

What I'm Looking For:

`https://example.com/example-01`

Example Code Below:

#Post.tsx

```
import "./Posts.css";
import Post from "../Post/Post";

const Posts = () => {
  const blogPosts = [
    {
      title: "Example 01",
      body: "Example Description",
      author: "John Doe",
      imgUrl: "https://image.jpg },
    {
      title: "Example 02",
      body: "Example Description",
      author: "Jane Doe",
      imgUrl: "https://image.jpg" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="posts-container">
      {blogPosts.map((post, index) => (
        <Post key={index} index={index} post={post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

#Post.tsx

```
import "./Post.css";
const Post = ({ post: { title, body,
imgUrl, author }, index }) => {
  return (  
    <div className="post-container">
      <h1 className="heading">{title}</h1>
      <img className="image" src={imgUrl} alt="post" />
      <div className="info">      
        <h4>Written by: {author}</h4>
      </div>
      <p>{body}</p>
      <p><a href={"/"+title}>Read More</a></p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: Why not do `"/" + title.replaceAll(" ", "-")`

Comment: That's simple and works like a charm. Make it an official answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Post` component, you can just replace all spaces in the title with dashes for the link target:

```
import "./Post.css";
const Post = ({ post: { title, body, imgUrl, author }, index }) => {
  return (  
    <div className="post-container">
      <h1 className="heading">{title}</h1>
      <img className="image" src={imgUrl} alt="post" />
      <div className="info">      
        <h4>Written by: {author}</h4>
      </div>
      <p>{body}</p>
      <p><a href={"/" + title.replaceAll(" ", "-")}>Read More</a></p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `slugify` npm package to make your title a slug:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify